# Sending JSON data in the body of Alamofire Request

Tags: php, json, api, swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to make an api call to submit some data using `Alamofire` (version 4.0). I think the request has succeed. But the trouble i'm having is that when making the call I get a response from the server that 0 byte FAILURE.

I have tried many of the solutions currently on StackOverflow and cannot find a solution. Thanks for your help.

**Here is my `Postman` setup:**

[image]

**My Swift code:**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [ "content-type": "x-www-form-urlencoded"]


        Alamofire.request("myurl.php?method=GET_RECENT", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**The error I'm getting is:**

> [Request]: myurl.php?method=GET_RECENT
>   [Response]:  { URL: myurl.php?method=GET_RECENT } { status code: 200, headers {
>       "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0";
>       Connection = "Keep-Alive";
>       "Content-Length" = 0;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
>       Date = "Sun, 01 Jan 2017 11:41:31 GMT";
>       Expires = "Sun, 01 Jan 2017 11:41:31 GMT";
>       "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=7, max=100";
>       Server = "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)";
>       "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.25";
>   } }
>   **[Data]: 0 bytes
>   [Result]: FAILURE:** responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)
>   [Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 504963459.698, "Initial Response Time": 504963459.821, "Request Completed Time": 504963459.821, "Serialization Completed Time": 504963459.821, "Latency": 0.123 secs, "Request Duration": 0.123 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.001 secs, "Total Duration": 0.124 secs }
>   Optional(myurl.php?method=GET_RECENT)
>   Optional( { URL: myurl.php?method=GET_RECENT } { status code: 200, headers {
>       "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0";
>       Connection = "Keep-Alive";
>       "Content-Length" = 0;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
>       Date = "Sun, 01 Jan 2017 11:41:31 GMT";
>       Expires = "Sun, 01 Jan 2017 11:41:31 GMT";
>       "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=7, max=100";
>       Server = "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)";
>       "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.25";
>   } })
>   **Optional(0 bytes)
>   FAILURE**

Comment: are you sure your request body is valid? That does not seem like a valid `JSON` to me. [This](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=7e091d9ddfc8638b36540ca465d2bba8) would more like it.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know yet JSON request has different with html. So Would you help me please?

Comment: can you show the code where you generate the JSON output? And the full JSON you are trying to post? Also, where do you receive exactly this error?

Comment: This is Postman view. I want download this data. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byvzu5SJNHYuMTNiRG5UdTdMN2M/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are setting your Postman setup is invalid. To send `JSON` as data in your `GET` request your should be using `raw` options, like on the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I solved it with another code! Your answer has helpful!